# Construct a Multidimensional Array

Tags: php

I am working in PHP with array iteration.

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [comments] => Testing the Data
            [stream_context_id] => 5
            [stream_entity_id] => 
            [class_id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [learnt_count] => 
            [rating_count] => 
            [abused_count] => 
            [created_by] => 1
            [created_datetime] => 
            [stream_context] => comments
            [name] => 
            [upload_path] => 
            [uploadby] => 
            [upload_time] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comments] => Testing the Data
            [stream_context_id] => 5
            [stream_entity_id] => 
            [class_id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [learnt_count] => 
            [rating_count] => 
            [abused_count] => 
            [created_by] => 1
            [created_datetime] => 
            [stream_context] => comments
            [name] => 
            [upload_path] => 
            [uploadby] => 
            [upload_time] => 
        )

)
```

Here the first index values i.e. 1 and 2 are the ids mentioned in their corresponding arrays.

I want the same multidimensional array with index values a 0 and 1 and so on.. i.e. the usual format of an array.

Comment: Would be useful to also tell us how you get the data in the first place

Comment: BTW, this is not a multidimensional array, it is a normal flat array with objects as values.

Comment: First, it's not a multidimensional array, it's an array of objects. Second, if you want to enumerate keys from 0 - n, loop trough the first array (one enumerated 1 - n) and create a new one that you enumerate 0 - n. However, I see no benefit in doing so, as it shouldn't be relevant whether the array key is 0 or 1, as long as the key is unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you meant, but maybe...:

```
$reindexedArray = array_values($yourArray);
```

If you also want to convert the `stdClass` objects to arrays, try:

```
$reindexedAndArrayifiedArray = array_values(array_map(function ($entry) {
    return (array)$entry;
}, $yourArray));
```

Comment: Thanks @Gus for the frequent Help

Answer (score 1):

Using `array_merge()` with a blank array - will renumber numeric indexes:

```
$result = array_merge(Array(), $your_array_here) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This does look like a multidimentional array as you have a named array holding objects.

Your array is currently:

```
$a = array('1'=>Object, '2'=>Object);
```

Instead of:

```
$a = array('1'=>array('id'=>'1', 'comment'=>'some comment'), '2'=>array());
$b = array();
foreach($a as $key=>$val){
    $b[] = $val;
}
```